# Typically how many digits are in a cheque number?

Tags: check

I'm writing an application and I'm trying to validate cheque numbers before I submit them for payment. From what I've found online cheque numbers are 6 digits in length, but I'm wondering if it's the same for other countries. I'm mostly concerned about western countries.

Comment: mine have three digits, USA.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. My (US) checks use as many digits as are needed to display the check number, with no leading or trailing zeros. The account number appears to be 14 digits and the routing number appears to be 9 digits.

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE].  As written this question will most likely be deleted because it is unclear what you're asking.  Which number on the check are you trying to validate?  The routing number, account number, check number, ...?  Will you be okay with an answer that is correct for the US but not for Canada/England?

Comment: I'm pretty sure people in most "Western countries" don't use checks regularly. It must be 20 years ago I last saw one myself, and even back then they were uncommon.

Comment: Business checks can have a much larger number. I just looked at one I deposited electronically from a business: the check number had ten digits.

Comment: There are companies that pay 400000 employess every payday, plus some odd millions suppliers. I think they would need 8 digits at least to not run out of them within some months.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Then I guess you have not been to the United States in 20 years... Checks remain very common here, and until a few years ago, they were basically the only practical means of moving money on a daily basis.  (Or is the US not a "Western country"?)

Comment: @NateEldredge OP wrote "I'm mostly concerned about western countries." Checks may "remain very common" in the United States, but insofar as I know, the United States is still just *one* country. The better part of Europe will definitely count as "western countries", too, for example.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Well, I read your comment as saying "Nobody uses checks anymore, so there's no point in supporting them in your application."  Even though the US is only one country, it's a very large one, and so leaving out support for checks would exclude a very significant part of the application's target market.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, I did not write "Nobody uses checks anymore, so there's no point in supporting them in your application.", did I?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I apologize for the misunderstanding.  But I wasn't sure what was the relevance of your comment on the usage of checks, unless it was meant as advice to the OP on whether they should care about the issue at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge The relevance was that "western countries", which the OP is "mostly concerned about", is quite broad. Any good answer to this thus must account for practices present in a potentially large number of "western countries", as well as any other countries that the OP may be concerned about which we don't know about ("mostly" implies that the set of countries of interest is larger than the example set which consists of "western countries").

Answer (score 1):

Checks are normally numbered sequentially, to keep them unique for record-keeping purposes. The check number takes as many digits as it takes, depending on how long the account has been open and thus how many checks have been written.  The most recent check I looked at had a four-digit number, but as has been pointed out businesses may run through thousands  per year.

I recommend storing this in an unsigned long or long-long, which will probably be comparable to the bank's own limits.

I don't know whether there is an explicit maximum value; we would need to find someone who knows the banking standards to answer that.

Comment: Is a cheque number guaranteed to always be strictly a number? Compare ISBNs or ISSNs which *look* like numbers (when written without the separator hyphens) but aren't, and until you encounter one where the check digit is `X`, you might have no idea.

Comment: There must be a standard someplace; if you want certainty you should track that down -- but at least in the US, I believe they are strictly numeric. Certainly every order form I've seen, from any check publisher l, asserts that, and every personal accounting program I've seen required that.

Comment: They are not strictly numbers, they can have characters. I too am interested if anyone knows of an RFC or some standards body definition of check numbers that may already exist. Another interesting aspect of check numbers is how they tend to be left padded with `0`'s which aren't semantically important.